# jQuery rating not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery star rating. My requirement is to get the value of star on button click..

Here is my code

```
<div id="Ratingdiv">
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="dynamic-control" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="dynamic-control" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="dynamic-control" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="dynamic-control" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" class="star" name="dynamic-control" value="5" />
</div>

<div style="padding: 20px">
    <form name="html-test" id="html-test">
    <input type="button" value="Insert control"      onclick="insert_dynamic_control(this.form);" />
    <div class="controls" style="padding: 5px; clear: both;">
</div>
<div style="padding: 5px; clear: both;">
     <input id="Button1" type="button" onclick="Getval();" value="button" />
    <span></span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

jQuery used on click is

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       {
          function Getval() {
              (function($) {
              $().ready(function() {
                var main = $('#Ratingdiv');
                main.each(function() {
                    var odds = $(main).find('.star');

                    alert(odds);

                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    }
```

I'm getting undefined on alert box.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xJqtB/

```
$(function() {
    $('#Button1').on('click', function(e){
        var main = $('#Ratingdiv');
        main.each(function() {
            var odds = $(main).find('.star:checked').val();

            alert(odds);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check demo

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepscet/NEEEB/2/

```
$('#Button1').click(function(){

   alert( $('input:radio[name=dynamic-control]:checked').val());


});
```

​